# New activity with ListView and adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, adapter

So, I want to start a new activity every time a person clicks on a child from the listView, but I don't know how. Firstly, I created string

```
<string-array name="title">
        <item>eeeeee </item>
        <item>wwwww </item>
        <item>qqqqq </item>
        <item>aaaaa </item>
        <item>nnnnn </item>
        <item>ccccc </item>
        


    </string-array>
```

After that I created one layout for the list, and one layout for the appearance of items in the listview.
I created an adapter, that looks like this :

```
public class InformatiiAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Informatii informatii;
    String[] title;
    Animation animation;

    public InformatiiAdapter(Informatii informatii, String[] title) {
        this.informatii = informatii;
        this.title = title;
    }
    public static int getRandom(int max)
    {
        return (int )(Math.random()*max);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return title.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(informatii).inflate(R.layout.new_item_layout, parent, false);
        animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(informatii, R.anim.animation1);
        TextView textView;
        LinearLayout ll_bg;
        ll_bg=convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_bg);
        textView=convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        int number=getRandom(8);
        if(number==1)
        {
            ll_bg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(informatii,R.drawable.gradient_1));
        } else if(number==2){
            ll_bg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(informatii,R.drawable.gradient_2));
        } else if(number==3){
            ll_bg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(informatii,R.drawable.gradient_3));
        } else if(number==4){
            ll_bg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(informatii,R.drawable.gradient_4));
        } else if(number==5){
            ll_bg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(informatii,R.drawable.gradient_5));
        } else if(number==6){
            ll_bg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(informatii,R.drawable.gradient_6));
        } else if(number==7){
            ll_bg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(informatii,R.drawable.gradient_7));
        } else if(number==8){
            ll_bg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(informatii,R.drawable.gradient_8));
        } else {
            ll_bg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(informatii,R.drawable.gradient_1));
        }

        textView.setText(title[position]);
        textView.setAnimation(animation);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And a mainactivity like this :

```
public class Informatii extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    Animation animation;
    String[] title;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_informatii);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Informații anxietate");

        listView=findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        title=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title);
        InformatiiAdapter adapter=new InformatiiAdapter(Informatii.this, title);
        animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.animation1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position==1){
                    Intent intent= new Intent(Informatii.this, Anxietate.class);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you see, I tried at onItemClick something like if position of the array is 1 , to go to another class, I will have 6-7 childs in the listview and I want to start a new activity for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `startActivity(intent)` after creating an intent to go there. You could do this with a series of if-else statements, a switch-case, or a list of destination classes. Remember that the `position` index starts at 0.

```java
Intent intent = null;
if( position == 0 ) {
    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Foo.class);
}
else if( position == 1 ) {
    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Bar.class);
}

if( intent != null ) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

```java
Intent intent = null;
switch(position) {
    case 0:
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Foo.class);
        break;
    case 1:
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Bar.class);
        break;
}

if( intent != null ) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

```java
List<Class<?>> destinations = Arrays.asList(
    Foo.class, 
    Bar.class
);

if( position < destinations.size() ) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, destinations.get(0));
    startActivity(i);
}
```